# Visual Studio Preview - 404 Not found error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, ecmascript-6

I am quite new to Visual Studio. I am running VS 2017 Preview version 15.7 for an angularjs project. I am running it in chrome browser ver 65. My angularjs project contains one library which has ecmascript-6 std javascript files. When I run the library from cdnjs I don't have any problem, but when I download and run it locally the library is not loading. I get errors in developer console for some files - "Could not load resource." "404 Not Found" errors. The resources are in the right directory, no typos. When I look at the Network tab of the console, the same files have been loaded correctly with 200 OK few seconds before.
I have set the "type=module" in my index.html files in the script tag.
Tried running it in an older VS 2013. Getting the same errors
What am I missing? Is it browser or VS issues?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out part of the problem. Adding the imported modules in the script tag to the index.html files. They will be automatically imported. I had to include only the main module. I still have the problem of "Syntax Error. Unexpected token = ". These are third party libraries downloaded to run locally.